# Moving CC in scrlttr2 to the top

Tags: positioning, letters

I would like to add a CC line between the address and the "yourref"-part.
Placing the `\cc` command just after `\begin{letter}` places the CC-text at the same place as the from-address. Is there any special koma-var for cc, or how can I place some cc lines in the head of a letter?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Joe Bloggs}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{21 Bridge Street \\ Smallville \\ Dunwich DU3 4WE}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{0123 45679}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{To this address}

\cc{Another person}

\setkomavar{subject}{subject}
\setkomavar{customer}[Personalnummer]{ABCDEF}
\setkomavar{place}{here}
\opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}
…

\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen,}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use the location field:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
  locfield=wide% <- added
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Joe Bloggs}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{21 Bridge Street \\ Smallville \\ Dunwich DU3 4WE}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{0123 45679}
\setkomavar{location}{{\setlength{\textwidth}{\useplength{locwidth}}{\cc{Another person}}}}% <- added
%\setkomavar*{ccseparator}{\makebox[1cm][r]{Kopien an}}

%% --- visualize field positions ---
%\LoadLetterOption{visualize}
%\showfields{address,location}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{To this address}
\setkomavar{subject}{subject}
\setkomavar{customer}[Personalnummer]{ABCDEF}
\setkomavar{place}{here}
\opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}
\ldots
\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

You can also change position, height and width of the location field:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Joe Bloggs}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{21 Bridge Street \\ Smallville \\ Dunwich DU3 4WE}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{0123 45679}
\setkomavar{location}{\cc{Another person}}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginLetter{%
  \@setplength{locwidth}{\useplength{firstheadwidth}}
  \@setplength[3]{locheight}{\baselineskip}
  \@setplength[-]{lochpos}{\useplength{toaddrhpos}}
  \@setplength{locvpos}{\useplength{refvpos}}
  \@addtoplength[-2]{locvpos}{\baselineskip}
  \@addtoplength{refvpos}{\baselineskip}
}
\makeatother

%% --- visualize field positions ---
%\LoadLetterOption{visualize}
%\showfields{address,location}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{To this address}
\setkomavar{subject}{subject}
\setkomavar{customer}[Personalnummer]{ABCDEF}
\setkomavar{place}{here}
\opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}
\ldots
\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

(Additional remark: Starting with version 3.26 it will be possible to use `\setplength` and `\addtoplength`. Then `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` can be removed from the example.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, actually this was my hacky solution with `textpos` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos} % <-- added this

\setkomavar{fromname}{Joe Bloggs}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{21 Bridge Street \\ Smallville \\ Dunwich DU3 4WE}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{0123 45679}

% Added this: This is needed to move the references line down, so we have place for the CC block
\makeatletter
\@addtoplength{refvpos}{1cm}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{To this address}

% Added this
\begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(2cm,9.5cm) % {block width} (coords) 
Kopie an: Another person
\end{textblock*}

\setkomavar{subject}{subject}
\setkomavar{customer}[Personalnummer]{ABCDEF}
\setkomavar{place}{here}
\opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}
…

\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen,}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

With this result:
[image: The Result]